How do I call custom MSBuild task before GenerateNuspec in multi-targeting project
I'm unable to use MSBuild tasks from referenced NuGet packages in the outer build of a multi-targeting project. The tasks run fine in the inner build (DispatchToInnerBuilds). I need to set some properties to version the package build (before GenerateNuspec) which happens after OuterPreBuild, but this always results in an error MSB4036: The "JsonPeek" task was not found.
Works fine for a single target project.
Here is a cut-down project that demonstrates the problem using JsonPeek.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Title>Test project.</Title>
    <Description></Description>
    <PackageIcon>Git2SemVer_icon_32x32.png</PackageIcon>
    <ApplicationIcon>Git2SemVer_icon_64x64.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <PackageReadmeFile>NuGet_description.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>false</SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>
    <GenerateDependencyFile>true</GenerateDependencyFile>
    <UpdateVersionProperties>true</UpdateVersionProperties>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageOutputPath>./nupkg</PackageOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\Documentation\Images\Git2SemVer_icon_32x32.png" Link="Git2SemVer_icon_32x32.png" Pack="True" PackagePath="\" />
    <Content Include="Git2SemVer_icon_64x64.ico" Pack="False" />
    <None Include="NuGet_description.md" Pack="True" PackagePath="\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="JsonPeek" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Semver" Version="[2.3.0]" />
    <PackageReference Include="Injectio" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Spectre.Console" Version="0.49.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="8.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

   <Target Name="OuterPreBuild" BeforeTargets="DispatchToInnerBuilds">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="========================================Outer before build" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="OuterPreBuild" AfterTargets="DispatchToInnerBuilds">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="========================================Outer after build: $(PackageVersion) | $(Git2SemVer_SharedVersioningJsonFile)" />

<!-- Note: Git2SemVer_SharedVersioningJsonFile is a valid property defined in a Directory.Build.props file that I have not included. -->

    <!-- ReSharper disable once UnknownTask -->
    <JsonPeek ContentPath="$(Git2SemVer_SharedVersioningJsonFile)" Query="$.Git2SemVerVersionInfo">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Git2SemVerVersionInfo" />
    </JsonPeek>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <Version>@(Git2SemVerVersionInfo -> '%(Version)')</Version>
      <VersionPrefix>@(Git2SemVerVersionInfo -> '%(VersionPrefix)')</VersionPrefix>
      <VersionSuffix>@(Git2SemVerVersionInfo -> '%(VersionSuffix)')</VersionSuffix>
      <PackageVersion>@(Git2SemVerVersionInfo -> '%(PackageVersion)')</PackageVersion>
      <InformationalVersion>@(Git2SemVerVersionInfo -> '%(InformationalVersion)')</InformationalVersion>
      <AssemblyVersion>@(Git2SemVerVersionInfo -> '%(AssemblyVersion)')</AssemblyVersion>
      <FileVersion>@(Git2SemVerVersionInfo -> '%(FileVersion)')</FileVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

  </Target>

</Project>

This gives an output (abbreviated):
1>Target DispatchToInnerBuilds:
1>  Target FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences:
1>    Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>      Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.

           :   lots of lines not shown

1>  Done building project "Common.csproj".
1>Target OuterPreBuild:
1>  ========================================Outer after build: 1.0.0 | C:\Sources\NoeticTools\Common\SolutionVersioningProject/.git2semver/Git2SemVer.VersionInfo.g.json
1>  C:\Sources\NoeticTools\Common\Common\Common.csproj(62,5): error MSB4036: The "JsonPeek" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64" directory.
1>Done building target "OuterPreBuild" in project "Common.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Done building project "Common.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>

I can use JsonPeek (as a demo) in the inner builds but not in the "outer build". I need to run it in the outer build to version the package, the binaries have been build with the correct versions.
Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible?

Edit:
Found the answer
To use MSBuild tasks from a NuGet package in the outer build (e.g: for GenerateNuspec), of a multitargeting project build, the package must include the props and targets files in a package folder buildmultitargeting.
I placed props and targets files in both buildmultitargeting and build folders that import the actual files in the tasks folder. I copied this from other projects. The files look like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tasks\$(MSBuildThisFile)" />
</Project>

The resulting NuGet package:


Your custom task is in a NuGet package and there is an import file with a <UsingTask> as part of the package?

If you use the /preprocess option on your project, do you see where and when JsonPeek.props and JsonPeek.targets are being imported? The issue might be that the outer build is not auto-importing the .props and .targets files from the package.

You could try the following for the outer build: Add GeneratePathProperty="true" to the PackageReference for JsonPeek. Add an ImportGroup with a Condition="$(JsonPeek) == ''". (Note that $(JsonPeek) will be defined with an value of true if the JsonPeek.props file has already been imported.) In the ImportGroup add explicit imports for the .props and .targets files using the package path property.

@JonathanDodds - yes, the task is in a Nuget package and it works fine if a single target like netstandard2.0. I've also tried with my own task-in-package with a . ... checking out your other suggestions ...

@JonathanDodds - You have taught me a lot with those suggestion - thx. But no luck, i does not work. It seems that it will only use that package reference when the TargetFramework is one set in TargetFrameworks. The outer build does not have a TargetFramework so not package loaded and the generated path property is empty (sigh). So it does seem that using MSBuild tasks in packages is not possible in a multi-targeting projects outer build - darn.  ... the /preprocess option was inconclusive but only showed the prop and target file import with TargetFramework conditions.

I may have found the answer: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/1860
